# How to get record by date from 1 table and update other table in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have two tables. In one table(order_produt) have multiple records by date and other table(Transfer_product) also multiple record by date. order_product table have correct record. i want update my transfer_product table with order_product table by date range.

```
order_product_table
-------------------------

id    | date         | Product_id  | value 
-------------------------------------------
1     | 2017-07-01   | 2           | 53
2     | 2017-08-05   | 2           | 67
3     | 2017-10-02   | 2           | 83
4     | 2018-01-20   | 5           | 32
5     | 2018-05-01   | 5           | 53
6     | 2008-08-05   | 6           | 67


Transfer_product_table
----------------------------

id    | date         | Product_id  | value 
--------------------------------------------
1     | 2017-08-01   | 2           | 10
2     | 2017-10-06   | 2           | 20
3     | 2017-12-12   | 2           | 31
4     | 2018-06-25   | 5           | 5

Result(Transfer_product_table)
--------------------------------
id    | date         | Product_id  | value 
--------------------------------------------
1     | 2017-08-01   | 2           | 53
2     | 2017-10-06   | 2           | 83
3     | 2017-12-12   | 2           | 83
4     | 2018-06-25   | 5           | 53
```

I want by date value update like you can see Result table.

i use query partion by but this is not what i want.

```
UPDATE Transfer_product_table imp
SET    value = sub.value 
FROM  (SELECT product_id,value 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY orderdate DESC)AS Rno
FROM order_product_table
where orderdate between '2017-07-01' and '2019-10-31') sub
WHERE  imp.product_id = sub.product_id 
and  sub.Rno=1
and imp.date between '2017-07-01' and '2019-10-31'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh Postgresql but when i post question stack overflow not post me question without select MySQL

Comment: For me it is not quiet clear how you get the expected results. Can you explain your use case more detailled? Escpecially the first value is not clear to me

Comment: @S-Man in 1st table i have received record from table and 2nd table transfer record different dates. i want update 2nd table(transfer_product) but using date range. if you check date 1st table then result table date value. value is in between range.

Comment: Why has the first (product = 2) record another value than the second?

Comment: @S-Man 2nd table transfer_product have wrong record.

Comment: Then please correct it ;)

Comment: @S-Man what you mean ?

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong record". What is wrong?

Comment: @S-Man in transfer_product have wrong record entry my dear. i need Result(Transfer_product_table) record

Comment: Yes and in your result it is not clear to why the first record has value 53 instead of 83

Comment: Becuase transfer product date '2017-08-01' and we look in order product '2017-08-01 ' before result. not latest date

Comment: Sorry, still do not understand it. I am out here. Maybe someone else could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using postgres' awesome daterange type.

```
with order_product_table as (
select * from (
  VALUES (1, '2017-07-01'::date, 2, 53),
         (2, '2017-08-05', 2, 67),
         (3, '2017-10-02', 2, 83),
         (4, '2018-01-20', 5, 32),
         (5, '2018-05-01', 5, 53),
         (6, '2008-08-05', 6, 67)
) v(id, date, product_id, value)
), transfer_product_table as (
select * from (
  VALUES (1, '2017-08-01'::date, 2, 10),
         (2, '2017-10-06', 2, 20),
         (3, '2017-12-12', 2, 31),
         (4, '2018-06-25', 5, 5)
) v(id, date, product_id, value)
), price_ranges AS (
  select product_id,
         daterange(date, lead(date) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id order by date), '[)') as pricerange,
         value
  FROM order_product_table
)
SELECT id,
       date,
       transfer_product_table.product_id,
       price_ranges.value
FROM transfer_product_table
JOIN price_ranges ON price_ranges.product_id = transfer_product_table.product_id
  AND date <@ pricerange
ORDER BY id
;
 id |    date    | product_id | value
----+------------+------------+-------
  1 | 2017-08-01 |          2 |    53
  2 | 2017-10-06 |          2 |    83
  3 | 2017-12-12 |          2 |    83
  4 | 2018-06-25 |          5 |    53
(4 rows)
```

Basically, we figure out the price at any given date by using the order_product_table.  We get the price between the current date (inclusive) and the next date (exclusive) with this:

```
         daterange(date, lead(date) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id order by date), '[)') as pricerange,
```

Then we simply join to this on the condition that the product_ids match and that date in the transfer_product_table is contained by the pricerange.